# What does it mean that something is transitive in programming?

Tags: c++

What does it mean that something is transitive with regard to programming? An example is the following (from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives)):

> Using-directives are transitive for the purposes of unqualified
>   lookup:

I am aware of the elaboration of this particular statement, however, I am striving for a more general programming related explanation.

Comment: The reference is using "transitive" for it's common meaning in formal logic.

Answer (score 9):

A binary relationship `~` is transitive if and only if `a ~ b` and `b ~ c` implies `a ~ c`.
(For instance, "is taller than" is transitive; "lives next door to" isn't.)

In this special case, A is `using` B, and B is `using` C, and it has the same effect as A `using` C directly.

Answer (score 7):

Transitive is a term from formal logic.   It means that "if A has a transitive relationship to B and B has the same relationship to C then A has that relationship to C".

For example, equality is a transitive relationship.   if `A == B` and `B == C` then transitivity is what allows `A == C` to be true.   Similarly, less-than is a transitive relationship, which means that if `A < B` and `B < C` then `A < C`.

For using directives, the meaning is that if a scope contains a using-directive that nominates a namespace name, which itself contains using-directive for a second namespace name, the effect is as if the using directives from the second namespace appear within the first.

In code, it means that

```
  namespace B
  {
        int foo;
  }

  namespace A   
  {
       using namespace B;
  }

  using namespace A;

  int main()
  {
      foo = 42;       // resolves to B::foo
  }
```

In the above, `foo` in `main()` resolves to `A::foo`.  Since `A` has a `using namespace B`,  `foo` in `main()` also resolves to `B::foo`.   Transitivity is the formal name for what makes that all work.